# Search for X at the beginning of a line within a multi-line string

Tags: sql-server

On SQL Server (2008), I have a column which is varchar(max).

I want to query for all rows where the blurb contains a lettered list:

```
Some sentence is here

a. foo
b. bar
c. baz

Some more text later
```

Can do this easily in regular expressions, but I do not have access to add regex capabilities to my instance.

So, How can I search using LIKE to find something like this? Presumably I would need to find where the first character of the line (in a multi-line blurb) is a character and 2nd is a dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to play with `CHAR(13)` and `CHAR(10)` depending on the source of the text, but this might be simply:

```
WHERE CHAR(10) + col LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '[A-Za-z].%'
------^^^^^^^^ in case the text *starts* with a lettered list
```

Note this will also find:

```
Some sentence is here

a. foo

Some more text later
```

If you need to only return rows where there is a list with two or more lines, you may not want to do this in the database, because it would require much more complicated parsing. In fact in that case - and if I couldn't perform the parsing outside the database (or in the database with CLR RegEx), I would probably use an ordered split function.

Comment: Thanks, that more or less did the trick, just needed to change `CHAR(13)` to `CHAR(10)`...  `R_MESSAGE LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '[A-Za-z].%'`

Comment: What's with the first `CHAR(13)`?

Comment: @Max ------^^^^^^^^ in case the text *starts* with a lettered list

Comment: @Max (and the list only contains one item)... it's not like that's going to slow this query down.

Comment: @aaron I had feeling it was edge-case related!  Thanks for the 'splanation!